# Get computed style only working using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the computed style (`background-color`) of an `span` element. This is my HTML, basically two `label` elements, with an `input` and a `span` elements inside:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="01" checked/>
  <span id="first-span">01</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="numbers" value="02" />
  <span>02</span>
</label>
```

A simple CSS to change the `background-color` of `span` when corresponding `input` is checked:

```
input:checked + span {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

And the JavaScript, where I'm calling the function `handleClick` on click event, responsible for print in the console the computed `background-color` of the first `span` element:

```
var span = document.getElementById('first-span');

function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(span, null);
  console.log(computedStyle.backgroundColor);
}

var numbers = document.getElementsByName('numbers');
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}
```

Even when I'm calling `e.preventDefault()` in the `handleClick` function (so the checked input don't change), I'm getting different `background-color` values. If first `input` is clicked, I get the correct value: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)`. But if the second `input` is clicked, I get the wrong `transparent` value.

A workaround I've found is to put the code inside a `setTimeout`, like:

```
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(span, null);
    console.log(computedStyle.backgroundColor);
  }, 0);
}
```

This works, but I really don't like it. So the question is:

> Can you provide a solution without using `setTimeout`? An explanation about why this happens would be great too, but not required actually :)

Check demos:

- [Not working properly (without `setTimeout`)](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/pd67s0wx/3/)
- [Working using `setTimeout`](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/pd67s0wx/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint at the call to `.preventDefault()` the visual radio button has already changed to having the 2nd input selected and CSS changes applied. Then it changes back after your code executes.

If you `.preventDefault` the `click` event, but check the `getComputedStyle()` during the `mouseup` event instead, then it works as you expect.

---

Edit:

[The DOM3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) states:

> Default actions **should** be performed after the event dispatch has been completed, but in exceptional cases **may** also be performed immediately before the event is dispatched.
>
> The default action associated with the **click** event on <input type="checkbox"> elements toggles the checked IDL attribute value of that element. If the click event's default action is cancelled, then the value is restored to its former state.

So it seems that it is acceptable for a browser to implement the controls in such a way that the default action happens first, then your `click` handler is called, then the browser "prevents the default" by undoing what it had already done.

This appears to be the case at least with Chrome and the radio buttons. It:

1. changes the "checked" state of the radio buttons to the one clicked (the 2nd one)
2. then calls your handler (which now sees the 2nd input as clicked, not the 1st)
3. your handler calls `.preventDefault()` which **flags** the event to be canceled (does not immediately do the cancelation)
4. sees the canceled flag on the event, and sets the first radio button back to "checked"

Comment: ...though I've yet to find a good explanation for why this happens.

Comment: Yeah, this is just another workaround, because I need to attach another event (`mouseup`) to the elements. The key here is that `e.preventDefault()` is not "preventing" properly, but why?

Comment: @Imgonzalves - I added an update and DOM spec reference to my answer above.

Comment: Now it's a GOOD answer :) Thank you very much!